# Why method addMedia() reset property?

Tags: laravel

I use [library](https://docs.spatie.be/). Created custom path generator:

```
class FilePathGenerator implements PathGenerator {
  public function getPath(Media $media) : string {
    return $media->model->getDirectory();
  }
  public function getPathForConversions(Media $media) : string {
    return $this->getPath($media) . 'conversions/';
  }
  public function getPathForResponsiveImages(Media $media): string {
    return $this->getPath($media).'/responsive/';
  }
}
```

In controller:

```
$client = Client::find($client_id)
$client->setCounterpartyDirectory(145);
SaveData::saveData( $client, 'client');
```

And class:

```
class SaveData {

  public static function saveData( $model, string $collectionName ) {

    $temp = tmpfile();

    fwrite($temp, json_encode('test'));

    $model->addMedia(stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri'])->toMediaCollection($collectionName);
    fclose($temp);
    return $model;
  }
}
```

In model:

```
 protected $counterpartyFolder = false;
```

Why before using method **addMedia()** `$this->counterpartyFolder; // 145` and after `$this->counterpartyFolder; // false` ?

Comment: Link to "library" is broken

Comment: @Styx I edited.